# Ethernet switch with Infiniband uplink

Tags: switch, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, infiniband

There are Ethernet switches (copper based, i.e. with RJ45 sockets) that have Fibre uplink. Example: [Netgear GS110TP](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/GS110TP.aspx#docs)

Are there any such switches with Infiniband uplinks? If not then why?

Comment: No, this is unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Ethernet and InfiniBand are two completely different and incompatible layer 2 protocols, for one. That's certainly sufficient. Don't confuse the physical media (layer 1) with the wire protocol (layer 2) that runs over the physical media.

Comment: So, are there any routers (layer 3) available then?

Comment: I suppose there's IPoIB but that probably won't solve whatever problem you are thinking about.

Comment: No, that won't solve my problem. My problem is that I have an Infiniband card in one computer and an Ethernet card in another computer and would like them to talk to each other.

Comment: In that case, get another Ethernet card or another InfiniBand card.

Comment: Sure, but I don't have any free PCIe slots left.

Comment: Then you need an dual-port card that can toggle between InfiniBand and Ethernet.  Or a different chassis with more expansion slots.